# React folder cannot be deleted on windows

Tags: reactjs

I did a react project on my Desktop folder in Windows. Now I am unable to delete it no matter what I do. I drag it into Recycling Bin and I right clicked to delete but nothing happens. I even used Unlocker and no luck.

Comment: This probably belongs in the [Superuser SA](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think its running behind.

So if you are on windows open `run` in going start menu and execute `resmon.exe` this command in it.
then it shows one window , then enter your folder name(that is to be deleted) in **Associative Handle** menu in it and `end the process`

Comment: No results found

Comment: did you entered correct folder name in it? Because it should work.

Comment: their are lots of file how to delete all of them at once ?